# Springboot : How to save nested associations using Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have two models namely **Company and User**. **A Company has many Users**.
When I save the company I need that the user be saved automatically.
Is there a way that JPA provides to achieve such thing?

Below are my models :

**//Company Model**

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 100)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 500)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public Company(){};

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

**//User Model**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 50, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String username;

    @Column(length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 50)
    private String password;

    @Column(length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(length = 50, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String email;

    private Boolean enabled;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull
    private Date lastPasswordReset;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_authority",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Authority> authorities;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Company company;

.... Followed by getters and setters
}
```

So the client sends a request payload consisting of a nested JSON object something like :

```
"company":{  
   "name":"Evil Corp",
   "description":"test",
   "users":[  
      {  
         "userName":"xyz",
         "password":"abc"         //folllowed by other attributes
      }
   ]
}
```

//Company Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/company")
public class CompanyController {

    @Autowired
    ICompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Company> create(@RequestBody Company company){
        System.out.println("Request Recieved");
        company = companyService.save(company);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(company);
    }
}
```

//Service

```
@Service
public class CompanyService implements ICompanyService {

    @Autowired
    CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Override
    public Company save(Company company) {
        return companyRepository.save(company);
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to save, I'm getting the following exception :

```
Hibernate: insert into user (company_id, created_at, email, enabled, first_name, last_name, last_password_reset, password, updated_at, username, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-03-11 15:15:57.814  WARN 7733 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2018-03-11 15:15:57.816 ERROR 7733 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'company_id' cannot be null
2018-03-11 15:15:57.853  INFO 7733 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2018-03-11 15:15:57.881 ERROR 7733 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

So how can I save the nested associations?
Do I manually need to set the company_id field in user once company is saved? I have achieved this kind of thing previously while working on **Rails**. Do such thing exists on Spring Boot as well?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: The User.company field **must** be non-null, as the error message says. So, initialize it before saving the company: `company.getUsers().forEach(user -> user.setCompany(company))`

Comment: That worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Company id is foreign key in user table so before saving parent and child objects together make sure the child object should have parent object set.

For example in your case - in User entity there is many to one relation like

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = 
  CascadeType.REMOVE)
 private Company company;
```

Set this company object to user object and then while persisting company object to database it's child objects auto inserted.
You have used **cascade = CascadeType.ALL** so it should insert child objects.